# Permission Issues on ArcGIS Server with SOC machines

Tags: arcgis-server

I am trying to figure out some permission issues for ArcGIS Server. I have 2 SOC machines that are associated with SOM. I noticed this problem when I added these SOC machines to SOM.
This service that I have published is a GP service.

Appreciate any ideas.

Thanks
Jay

First Error: 
~~~~~~~~
WARNING Can not open directory c:\arcgisserver\arcgisoutput. The system cannot find the path specified. Probable cause: The network path is inaccessible to ArcGIS Server Object Container account. 2011-11-08 11:14:15 SDM.ServerDirectoryManager cwf414

Second Error:
~~~~~~~~~~~ 
ERROR Can not open file D:\Projects\GPServices.mxd. The system cannot find the path specified. Probable cause: The file is inaccessible to Server. 2011-11-08 11:07:31 PRJ/GPServices.MapServer cwf415

ERROR Server Object instance creation failed on machine cwf415. Can not open file D:\Projects\GPServices.mxd. The system cannot find the path specified. Probable cause: The file is inaccessible to Server.  2011-11-08 11:07:31 PRJ/GPServices.MapServer cwf415

ERROR Server Object instance creation failed on machine cwf415. Can not open file D:\Projects\GPServices.mxd. The system cannot find the path specified. Probable cause: The file is inaccessible to Server.  2011-11-08 11:07:31 PRJ/GPServices.MapServer cwf415

Comment: On all these two folders, my SOC account for the main server (SOM machine) has read/write permissions. Do I need to add the two SOC accounts for permissions explicitly.

Comment: Is the SOC user account a domain account?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, to start with you will want to have a UNC path setup that you can use to have both of your SOC machines publish to; since the SOM is going to use both. This is where you will want to point your ArcGISOutput and ArcGISJobs folders. 
You are going to need to make sure your SOC account has full access between those shared directories so that you can read-write to them.
It also looks like the SOCs are not being able to see where your MXD file is; so you probably need to setup a UNC path for this; and have your SOM connect to that; or you can copy the exact same path to your SOCs (which can be faster loading/processesing since there is reduced network traffic) and have them use a local drive letter.

Comment: Folder clarification: I am curious if SOC machines need to have their own directories for arcgisoutput, arcgisjobs, arcgisinput, arcgiscache. My SOM server has these folders and is shared

Comment: Clarification for SOC account: Are you referring to  SOC account for SOM/SOC machine or the two addtional SOC machines. I can access these folders from other machines so these are accessible.

Comment: To make this work best; you should use the same accounts across all machines that talk together; since they need to be able to read-write and communicate. Your SOC machines should write to your SOM directories (from my fuzzy memory) this is why they need permission.

Comment: SOC does all the work. wherever that may be. (arcgisoutput folder)

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you might want to check out the Esri Help pages for ArcGIS Server - Configuring a multiple-machine deployment, starting with the "Prepare any server directories that your server will use" section.

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/help/arcgis_server_dotnet_help/index.html#//0093000000m7000000.htm